# What does `bless` do inside a brace construct?

Tags: perl

```
my $self; { my %hash; $self = bless(\%hash, $pkg); }
```

It's quoted from `HTML/Template.pm`,why not simply `bless $self,$pkg`?

Answer (score 4):

I think the intention was to limit the scope of `%hash` to the enclosing block. This can be rewritten as:

```
my $self = bless {}, $pkg;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $hash  =   {};
 ^^^^^      ^^
referrer referent
```

In the following statement:

```
$self = bless( $hash, $pkg );
```

[`bless`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) marks the referent (the anonymous hash) to which `$hash` refers, as being an object of `$pkg` (the HTML::Template class).  It does not alter the `$hash` variable.

The `bless` function returns a reference to the blessed anonymous hash.  `$self` therefore becomes a reference to the blessed anonymous hash (the referent).

It is important to remember that if the the first argument to the `bless` function is a reference, it is the thing to which it refers that is blessed, not the variable itself:

```
$self = bless( $self, $pkg );
```

`$self` doesn't refer to anything - it is `undef`.  There is no referent to bless.  It is equivalent to attempting this:

```
$self = bless( undef, $pkg );
```

[Bless My Referents](http://www.perl.com/pub/1999/09/refererents.html) provides a great introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$self` is `undef` - Almost equivalent would be:

```
my $self ={}; { $self = bless($self, $pkg); }
```

Or :

```
$self = bless( {}, $pkg);
```

**Edit** to answer comment:

You can't bless an undef, because you'll get the error `Can't bless non-reference value at ...`. This is because only hard references may be blessed. This is how Perl *enforces* encapsulation of objects. See the [perlobj manpage](http://www.xav.com/perl/lib/Pod/perlobj.html).

Comment: Do you mean `undef` vars can't be blessed?

Comment: I mean `undef` is not the same as a hash ref :)

Comment: why can't I bless it first and initialize it later?

Comment: @Learning, because it's the _reference_ that gets blessed, not the variable.  You can't bless `undef` because it's not a reference.

Comment: @cjm ,what about `bless \$self,$pkg;`?

Comment: @Learning, that doesn't put a blessed reference in `$self`, it returns a blessed reference _to_ `$self` (which will then be discarded if you don't store it somewhere).

Comment: that would be a blessed scalar reference, not a blessed hash reference